# Inserir Linha de Comando no typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, cmd, electron, .exe

Tenho um Script de instalção e configuração do MongoDB conforme a necessidade da Empresa.

Install_MongoDB.BAT

Mas gostaria de Automatizar esse processo incluindo no projeto em TypeScript.
Gostaria de Inserir comandos que criei no .bat e incluir num Projeto já concluido e Depois Gerar um Executavel com Electron.

Como poderia inserir os comandos do CMD dentro do TypeScript ?
Qual seria melhor forma ?

Comment: Você diz, executar um comando no terminal com o typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para executar um comando no terminal usando o TypeScript, você pode utilizar a função [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) da biblioteca nativa do NodeJS `child_process`. Com ela, você pode fazer:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'

exec("mkdir test", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        // Caso o Node não consiga efetuar o comando
        return console.error(err)
    }
    // Resultado do programa
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    // Caso o node execute mas o comando encontre algum erro
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
})
```

Esse código irá executar o comando no terminal `mkdir test` criando o diretório `test` se tudo der certo. Você pode adaptar o código para cumprir as suas necessidades com o Electron. Vale ressaltar, que esse código deve ser rodado no `main` do Electron, que é a que possui acesso à biblioteca do Node. Daí, você pode usar os eventos, para através do cliente chamar o código no "backend".